# Change a JavaFX node's parent in a single Add+Remove event, not two separate events

Tags: javafx, javafx-11

I want to move a child node from one parent's child list to another parent's child list without triggering a listener for the "null parent" case. I do so with only a single command:

```
newParent.getChildren().add(child)
```

But this triggers two separate change events on `child.parentProperty`:

```
oldParent -> null
null -> newParent
```

This causes problems in my user interface.  I have a tab pane, where each tab allows **selecting** a node in the tab, such that when you navigate to another tab, then back to the first tab, the node is still selected. A listener **deselects** that node when the tab is no longer in the node's ancestry, that is, when the node is removed from the tab.

Naturally, the first of the two events is triggering the listener, removing the node from the tab, even if temporarily, and so deselecting the node.

What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: You don't have access to how the `parent` is set. Perhaps if you provide a [mre] of what you're trying to do then someone could offer a solution (e.g. select the node again once it's added back to a parent).

Comment: That is quite unfortunate. Another way is to alter the listener to account for this case, and that is what I ended up doing.